# Webpack HMR with React and third party library

Tags: reactjs, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I have a React app with a webpack build. I am using Webpack HMR using React-Hot-Loader.
I configured it as the documentation, and everything is working fine except for one place.

I have a non-react library to display map from map-box API (mapbox-gl).

In the react component, I create a `<div>` with `ref`, and initialize the mapbox-gl code into the `ComponentDidMount` method.
I run this code on ComponentDidMount:

```
ComponentDidMount() {

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: this._map_div_ref,
           .....
        })
}
```

When this map is used in webpack-HMR, the code on ComponentDidMount doesn't run, so when the HMR update the browser, it empty the map_div

Is there a way to tell webpack-HMR to run that code?

Comment: Can you share an example in codesandbox?

Comment: unfortunately, there is lots of setup for the map to show. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your map instantiation above your class header but below your imports. For example:

```
import React ...

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
// map options 
)}

class Map extends Component {
```

**Edit:** Have you also considered using a react wrapper for Mapbox, such as [react-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md) or [react-map-gl](https://uber.github.io/react-map-gl/#/)? I would look into those to see if it would be easier to display and play around with the map. I currently use react-mapbox-gl, but I am unaware of how well it would work with Webpack HMR.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not that easy to use the react wrapper for mapbox-gl (react-mapbox-gl). the team told me that this wrapper didn't support what they wanted to do.

Back to your suggestion, I cannot do that, because I have to pass to the mapbox the div name which I am getting from the React's Ref property that I am creating.